# Получение данных с помощью Retrofit из Json, имеющего несколько уровней

Tags: android, json, kotlin, api, retrofit

Есть Json:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Hayley O'Keefe",
        "description": "Eveniet sed exercitationem distinctio voluptatum qui magnam ratione et soluta itaque explicabo laborum nemo mollitia et veniam aut sed voluptatibus at sequi aut consequatur labore quod vel iusto...",
        "date": "1991-03-24"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Terry Schaefer",
        "description": "Consectetur explicabo porro quis debitis itaque corrupti eius beatae aliquid facilis ea quo soluta porro est facere ut quia sit provident suscipit ut eos inventore est aperiam nostrum sit reprehenderit...",
        "date": "1988-08-27"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Jude Sporer DVM",
        "description": "Explicabo illum et excepturi doloremque quidem laboriosam excepturi quae fugit nostrum et enim enim libero vitae sit perspiciatis quis consequatur eum ratione sequi doloribus voluptatem velit commodi...",
        "date": "1984-02-14"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Prof. Leola Rogahn",
        "description": "Quia iste id sint repellat debitis illo ex et commodi et repellendus consequuntur consequatur modi molestiae...",
        "date": "2005-10-29"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Jaylon VonRueden",
        "description": "Aspernatur sit iusto enim asperiores est quis autem tempore fuga qui omnis inventore nostrum ab debitis ducimus voluptatem quia ipsa placeat molestiae dolores doloremque ipsa tempore vero...",
        "date": "2019-04-09"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Margie Kertzmann",
        "description": "Aut itaque non expedita laborum vero inventore ipsa commodi nobis accusantium hic aspernatur ab fuga molestiae dignissimos eaque voluptatum sapiente totam et exercitationem dolorem qui tempora...",
        "date": "2020-12-10"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Monserrat Kulas",
        "description": "Eum sunt eius ab sit qui soluta quisquam quam qui vel eaque exercitationem error necessitatibus aspernatur qui optio et qui doloribus necessitatibus aut et reprehenderit doloremque non et dolor...",
        "date": "1976-02-25"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Dr. Filomena Pagac PhD",
        "description": "Dolores nostrum fugiat incidunt et sapiente sunt dolores et illo magnam repudiandae dolores et voluptas inventore error iusto rem ut aperiam quo similique eveniet ut culpa veniam recusandae pariatur delectus...",
        "date": "1984-02-05"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Camden Armstrong",
        "description": "Est aspernatur tempore necessitatibus rerum aut placeat incidunt molestias molestiae voluptatem at non vitae...",
        "date": "1980-04-05"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Jade Mosciski",
        "description": "Quis odio ut nihil non eum accusamus voluptatem minus deleniti non tempora eligendi ullam consequatur dignissimos ....",
        "date": "1978-04-05"
      }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 10,
    "last_page_url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=10",
    "links": [
      {
        "url": null,
        "label": "&laquo; Previous",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=1",
        "label": "1",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=2",
        "label": "2",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=3",
        "label": "3",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=4",
        "label": "4",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=5",
        "label": "5",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=6",
        "label": "6",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=7",
        "label": "7",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=8",
        "label": "8",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=9",
        "label": "9",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=10",
        "label": "10",
        "active": false
      },
      {
        "url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=2",
        "label": "Next &raquo;",
        "active": false
      }
    ],
    "next_page_url": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books?page=2",
    "path": "http://candidate.scid.ru/api/books",
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 10,
    "total": 100
  },
  "error": null
}
```

Если разложить его на модели, получится следующая иерархия (если я ничего не перепутал):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

сами модели:

`Pagination`:

```
data class Pagination(
    val error: Any,
    val result: Result,
    val success: Boolean
)
```

`Result`:

```
data class Result(
    val current_page: Int,
    val `data`: List<Data>,
    val first_page_url: String,
    val from: Int,
    val last_page: Int,
    val last_page_url: String,
    val links: List<Link>,
    val next_page_url: String,
    val path: String,
    val per_page: Int,
    val prev_page_url: Any,
    val to: Int,
    val total: Int
)
```

`Data`:

```
data class Data(
    val date: String,
    val description: String,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

`Link`:

```
data class Link(
    val active: Boolean,
    val label: String,
    val url: String
)
```

Мне нужно получать данные только из `Data`

И тут возникает проблема. Так как мне нужно 2 раза "обернуть" `Data` в модели, стоящие выше по иерархии, я создаю, для этих целей, следующие классы:

`PaginationApiModel`:

```
class PaginationApiModel {

    @SerializedName("result") @Expose
    val result: ResultApiModel? = null

}
```

`ResultApiModel`:

```
class ResultApiModel {

    @SerializedName("data") @Expose
    val data: ArrayList<Data>? = null

}
```

Но мне нужно получать массив данных из Json, ввиду чего я не очень понимаю, как мне реализовать этот фрагмент класса `ApiDataSourceIMPL`, если я заменю `ArrayList<Data>` на `PaginationApiModel`:

```
        for (audit in loadNameList) {

            audit.id?.let {
                PaginationLocalModel(
                    it,

                    audit.name.toString(),
                    audit.date.toString(),
                    audit.description.toString(),

                )
            }?.let {
                dataSource.insert(
                    it
                )
            }
```

Вот так выглядит мой класс `ApiDataSourceIMPL` сейчас:

```
class ApiDataSourceIMPL (private val dataSource: RDDataSource):
    ApiDataSource {

    override fun startMigration (context: Context) {

    val call = ApiClient.instance?.api?.loadApi()
    call?.enqueue(object: Callback <ArrayList<Data>>
     {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<ArrayList<Data>>,
            response: Response<ArrayList<Data>>
        ) {

            Log.d("ApiDataSource", "onResponse status: ${response.code()}")

            var loadNameList: ArrayList<Data>? = null

           // loadNameList?.clear()

            loadNameList = (response.body() as ArrayList<Data>?)!!
                  

            for (audit in loadNameList) {

                audit.id?.let {
                    PaginationLocalModel(
                        it,

                        audit.name.toString(),
                        audit.date.toString(),
                        audit.description.toString(),

                    )
                }?.let {
                    dataSource.insert(
                        it
                    )
                }

            }

            Toast.makeText(context, "ЗАГРУЗКА", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call <ArrayList<Data>>
   
                               , t: Throwable) {
            t.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(context, "ОШИБКА! ВКЛЮЧИТЕ ИНТЕРНЕТ!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e("ApiDataSource2", "onFailure", t)
        }
    })

}

}
```

Модель локальной базы данных:

```
@Entity(tableName = "pagination_table")
class PaginationLocalModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    val date: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String

)
```

Локальная база данных:

```
@Database(entities = [PaginationLocalModel::class], version = 1)
abstract class ReceiveDataDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val nameListDao : NameListDao
    abstract val descriptionDao : DescriptionDao

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Фрагмент с циклом не меняется, меняется поход за ссылкой на список:

```kotlin
loadNameList = response.body().result.data
```

*P.S.* вместо класса `Data` вы можете использовать в json модели сразу `PaginationLocalModel` - они же идентичны